# Estimates on the density of hitting time for planar Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Consider a polygon $\Pi \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and let $T_{\Pi,x}$ be the (random) time a Brownian motion started at a point $x$ in its interior first crosses $\Pi$.

For any such $\Pi$, do there exist $C,c >0 $ and $\nu \in (0,1]$ such that $T_{\Pi,x}$ has a density satisfying

$$ p_{\Pi,x}(t) \le C \left( \frac{R(x)}{\sqrt t}\right)^\nu \frac1t \exp(- c R^2(x)/t) $$
where $R(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $\Pi$, that is
$$ \mathbb P [a < T_{\Pi,x} < b] \le C R^\nu(x)\int_a^b \frac{\exp(- c R^2(x)/t)}{t^{1+\nu/2}} dt?$$

For a rectangle or equilateral triangle this can be checked using the reflection principle and unless I've made a silly mistake it is true with $\nu=1$; from what I know about the behavior of the heat kernel with Dirichlet boundary conditions I would expect this to be true for general convex polygons, and for non-convex polygons only with $\nu < 1$.

Comment: The tails of T should be exponential at worst, and this do not seem to be.

Comment: @mike that's correct, but this is just supposed to be an upper bound.  If the bound I wrote is true it's probably still true if you add a factor like $\exp(-c t/V_\Pi)$ with $V_\Pi$ the volume of the interior.